# How to automatically retrieve the consumed ML unit in finished ai-platform jobs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am hosting an application on google cloud platform.

From time to time, I will need to submit an `ai-platform` training job using the Python's client for Google.

Now I also want to keep track of the prices I consumed under the `ai-platform`. I know that the prices can be computed by `consumed ML units * $0.49`. However, is there an elegant way to keep track of those consumed ML units rather than looking up all of them by hand?

Ideally I would like something similar to the `log-router` that automatically grab the consumed ML units once a job is finished and dump the result to somewhere I can specify.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The more rudimentary way to calculate the price is with the Google Cloud pricing calculator[1].

Also, you can make use of labels to gain visibility into GCP resources [2]

I hope it helps.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator

[2] https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/cost-management/use-labels-to-gain-visibility-into-gcp-resource-usage-and-spending